# Specifying "the most recent commit" to git filter-branch when there is only one commit?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have script that performs some automatic commit message rewrites on a set of commits using `git filter-branch`.  By default, it only operates on the most recent commit, which is specified as `HEAD^..` (that is, all commits between the first parent of this commit and this commit).  That works fine, but fails if HEAD is the root commit:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^..': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Is there a way to specify a range of commits consisting of only the top commit that will work in both situations?  Or would I need to implement special handling to detect the root commit?

Note that while simply using `HEAD` will work great when there is only a single commit, but that it really means "all commits in this branch" so does not work in the situation in which there are more than a single commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're writing the script, and are looking for a branch-name-based range specifier you can easily feed to `git rev-list` that means: *this one commit, and no others*, but also works when the base specifier points to a root commit.

There *is* one such range specifier:

```
${name} ^${name}^@
```

(which for some reason cannot be spelled `${name}^@..${name}`, it *must* be the two separate arguments).  The `^@` means "all parents of the given revision, but not the given revision", so the `^` in front that negates this excludes all the parents.  If there are no parents, it excludes nothing, which achieves what we want anyway.

A much simpler option is to pass a literal `--no-walk`.  This is a little bit different; experiment with what you (or filter-branch) will pass to `git rev-list` to see.  You could supply the `--no-walk HEAD` only when you're not given an argument range.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.  I don't think that `--no-walk` is appropriate because I do want to be able to handle ranges (and I don't want to have to detect, in my own code, whether or not a given argument represents a range of commits or not).

Comment: It looks like `name ^name^@` makes `rev-list` happy, but `filter-branch` still complains (which is surprising given that the docs suggest very strongly that it accepts pretty much whatever `rev-list` accepts).

Comment: Hm, not only that, but I tried feeding it to the `git rev-parse` that `git filter-branch` uses to compute which branch(es) to update at the end, and rev-parse is good with it.

Comment: Wait, it is?  `git rev-parse HEAD ^HEAD^@` for me yields the same error I see with `filter-branch`. I am beginning to think my best option is just to check `IF <the arguments result in a single commit> AND <that commit has no parents> THEN...`

Comment: The parse I was testing is `git rev-parse --no-flags --revs-only --symbolic-full-name --default HEAD "$@"`, partway through the filter-branch code.

Comment: By the way, you can tell if a commit is a root commit using `git rev-parse` again. First translate the input to a commit hash (in case the input is something like `:/fixme` where suffixing breaks, plus this also verifies that the string translates): `hash=$(git rev-parse "$arg") || die ...`. Then use `root=true; git rev-parse --quiet --verify $hash^1 >/dev/null && root=false`. (If the commit has at least one parent, it's not a root commit.) Now you can just run `if $root; then ...` or `$root && echo ...` etc.